# there are many jump points when i plot by using plot3D

Tags: plotting

this bug bothers me for a long time, i would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

```
Kz1 = (wp (\[Kappa] - 
 Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2]
   Sqrt[(-wp^2 \[Kappa]^2 + wc wp (1 - \[Kappa]^2)^(3/2) - 
   wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))/((-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (wp^2 + 
     wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)))]))/Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2];
Kz2 = (wp (\[Kappa] + 
 Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2]
   Sqrt[(-wp^2 \[Kappa]^2 + wc wp (1 - \[Kappa]^2)^(3/2) - 
   wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))/((-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (wp^2 + 
     wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)))]))/Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2];
Kz3 = -((wp (\[Kappa] + 
  Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2]
    Sqrt[-((
    wp^2 \[Kappa]^2 + wc wp (1 - \[Kappa]^2)^(3/2) + 
     wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))/((-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (wp^2 + 
       wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))))]))/Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2]);

Kz4 = (wp (-\[Kappa] + 
 Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2]
   Sqrt[-((
   wp^2 \[Kappa]^2 + wc wp (1 - \[Kappa]^2)^(3/2) + 
    wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))/((-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (wp^2 + 
      wc^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2))))]))/Sqrt[1 - \[Kappa]^2];
\[Kappa] = 0.5;
Plot3D[{Kz1, Kz2, Kz3, Kz4}, {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
```

I update my question. what i want is like the following figure:
[image: Ref:https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-021-24189-3]
But the result of my code got a lot of unwanted solutions, a lot of vertical lines.
[image]
I think these unwanted solutions are caused by a denominator of 0, but i didn't kwno how to solve this bug. :(

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Having said that, are you aware that `Kz2`, `Kz3`, and `Kz4` are undefined? Also, can you explain what the actual issue is? I am asking because I ran the code without any errors. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To limit artifacts increase `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, and `WorkingPrecision` (at the cost of significantly slower plot evaluation).

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

κ = 1/2;

Kz1 = (wp (κ - 
        Sqrt[
          1 - κ^2] Sqrt[(-wp^2 κ^2 + 
             wc wp (1 - κ^2)^(3/2) - 
             wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))/((-1 + κ^2) (wp^2 + 
               wc^2 (-1 + κ^2)))]))/Sqrt[1 - κ^2] // Simplify;

Kz2 = (wp (κ + 
        Sqrt[
          1 - κ^2] Sqrt[(-wp^2 κ^2 + 
             wc wp (1 - κ^2)^(3/2) - 
             wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))/((-1 + κ^2) (wp^2 + 
               wc^2 (-1 + κ^2)))]))/Sqrt[1 - κ^2] // Simplify;

Kz3 = -((wp (κ + 
          Sqrt[
            1 - κ^2] Sqrt[-((wp^2 κ^2 + 
                 wc wp (1 - κ^2)^(3/2) + 
                 wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))/((-1 + κ^2) (wp^2 + 
                   wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))))]))/Sqrt[1 - κ^2]) // 
   Simplify;

Kz4 = (wp (-κ + 
        Sqrt[
          1 - κ^2] Sqrt[-((wp^2 κ^2 + 
               wc wp (1 - κ^2)^(3/2) + 
               wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))/((-1 + κ^2) (wp^2 + 
                 wc^2 (-1 + κ^2))))]))/Sqrt[1 - κ^2] // 
   Simplify;
    
Plot3D[{Kz1, Kz2, Kz3, Kz4},
 {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 4,
 WorkingPrecision -> 25,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {Subscript[ω, c], 
     Subscript[ω, p], Kz}),
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But WHAT I want to do now is get rid of the unnecessary solutions, like the black side of the answer that you gave. I want to get a clear figure like the first i posted in my question. I wonder if my expression is clear. If you have any new ideas, I will be available at any time

Answer (score 0):

It is worthwhile to make a `Table` of the values of `Kz1`

```
Table[Table[Kz1, {wp, 0, 2}], {wc, -5, 5}] // Chop // TableForm
```

[image: pl1]

Now, to address the jumps -which if I understand correctly are the white lines- you can do the following:

```
Plot3D[Kz1, {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: pl2]

However, plotting the real and imaginary parts is more resilient in my opinion and can be done as follows:

```
Plot3D[Re@Kz1, {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
Plot3D[Im@Kz1, {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: pl3]

[image: pl4]

edit: addressing the new point

With the definitions of the OP the following seems to work

```
Plot3D[{Kz1, Kz2, Kz3, Kz4}, {wc, -5, 5}, {wp, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image: plnew]

Comment: thanks a lot. I update my question and add which issue i want to solve.

Comment: @ZhongfuLi I updated my answer. Seems close to what you provide in the original post, right?

Comment: It would be perfect if we didn't have those two black planes along the z axis.  :(              I just wanted to get rid of those two black planes